# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in Android Login&Register

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-studio

I have a problem creating a login and registration in java. I am able to create a user however it returns error. It returns JSON + Error. 
   This is the JSON and error when I try to log in:

```
D/RegisterActivity: Login Response: login.php
                DB_Connect.php
                    Config.php
                {"error":false,"uid":"592da509e15a88.38765516","user":{"name":"P","email":"p","created_at":"2017-05-30 17:59:53"}}

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value login.php of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:at activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:125)
W/System.err:at activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:117)
```

This is the login.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnLinkToRegister;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(email, password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}}
```

login.php code:

```
  <?php
 require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
 $db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

// receiving the post params
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// get the user by email and password
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

if ($user != false) {
    // use is found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["NAME"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user is not found with the credentials
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required post params is missing
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I have spend hours on this could anyone point me in the right direction ? Thank you

Comment: I can see in the log that response has more than the json, there are also php file names and I think is for that there is a JSONException. You sholud  take only the json from the response.

Comment: what is the actual login response?  >>> Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString()); // Post your full  login.php code also

Comment: I have posted the full login.java and full login.php @FAT

Comment: Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString()); prints ??? I  think your attached log message is wrong.

Comment: @FAT You have it in the first code snipet.  Login Response: login.php
                    DB_Connect.php
                        Config.php
                    {"error":false,"uid":"592da509e15a88.38765516","user":{"name":"P","email":"p","created_at":"2017-05-30 17:59:53"}}

Comment: are your getting string " login.php DB_Connect.php Config.php " with your resposne?

Comment: @FAT Yes I do . I will check this why I get that

Comment: This is the problem. Your response is not an JSON formatted string that's why its unable to create JSONObject from this string.

Comment: It is working . I have made a mistake yesterday by adding the name of the file at the top of the file which was keep being added to the String. Thank you for you Help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Login Response: `login.php DB_Connect.php Config.php`
>   `{"error":false,"uid":"592da509e15a88.38765516","user":{"name‌​":"P","email":"p","c‌​reated_at":"2017-05-‌​30 17:59:53"}}`

As per your attached response `message`, it seems totally `wrong`.

Your response is not an `JSON` formatted `string` that's why its unable to create `JSONObject` from this `response` string.

**Make sure your response contains only `JSONObject`:**

`{"error":false,"uid":"592da509e15a88.38765516","user":{"name‌​":"P","email":"p","c‌​reated_at":"2017-05-‌​30 17:59:53"}}`

Remove unnecessary string `"login.php DB_Connect.php Config.php"` from response message. Check your server side code, why its adding string `"login.php DB_Connect.php Config.php"` with `JSONObject`.

I think this will solve your problem.